# Create react app production build very slow on high end machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs

we are having issues with the performance of production build.
It takes around 20 minutes to build.
We thought maybe it's our machine, so we ran it on a server with 32 core and 128gb ram.

The build still took around 20 minutes and the CPU usage only peaked to 20% and the memory peaked to around 2gb.

I have included a copy of our package.json file for reference;

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-buttons": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-circulargauge": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids": "^17.4.55",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-inputs": "^17.4.55",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-navigations": "^18.1.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-pdfviewer": "^18.1.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-pivotview": "^18.1.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-popups": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule": "^17.4.55",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-splitbuttons": "^17.4.55",
    "@types/react-mic": "^12.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bulma": "^0.8.2",
    "bulma-extensions": "^6.2.7",
    "cb-react-forms": "^1.1.0",
    "clientjs": "^0.1.11",
    "globalize": "^1.5.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-beforeunload": "^2.2.1",
    "react-data-table-component": "^3.10.3",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.12.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-mic": "^12.4.6",
    "react-quiz-component": "^0.3.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^1.24.0",
    "videojs": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env  NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=12192 react-scripts start",
    "build": "cross-env  NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=12192  react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^8.0.4",
    "@types/ej.web.all": "^18.1.2",
    "@types/globalize": "^0.0.34",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.13",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/node": "12.0.7",
    "@types/react": "16.8.19",
    "@types/react-big-calendar": "^0.22.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "@types/react-pdf": "^4.0.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/styled-system": "^4.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gzipper": "^3.7.0",
    "husky": "^3.1.0",
    "mockdate": "^2.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-testing-library": "^8.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "typesafe-actions": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3",
    "yarn": "^1.22.4"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-push": "yarn test"
    }
  }
}
```

When running dev/start, it takes about a minute. Any suggestions on how to improve the build times?

Comment: You could try profiling the build with the inspector. Running `node --inspect-brk --inspect node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js build` will open the inspector listener at 127.0.0.1:9229, to which you can connect Chrome's devtools from `chrome://inspect/`. Since this is a remote server, you could start the node process and open an ssh tunnel to forward the port 9229 to your own computer: `ssh -N -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 user@server`, after which you'll see it in the Chrome's inspect page.

Comment: Then, just start the profiler in the Performance tab and start the execution in the Sources tab (since `--inspect-brk` tells node to breakpoint immediately and wait for a debugger to continue)

Comment: Hopefuly that will give you at least some visibility into what's taking long - perhaps it's disk ops if you're running in a container where the host is Windows or macOS and the container is using a linux distro? Perhaps it's death by a thousand cuts [due to the way you import things?](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4791#issuecomment-423045091)

Comment: Which version of node are you using by the way?

Comment: Thanks will try, node version is 12.16.3

Comment: I've updated to nodejs 14.3.0 and the performance has vastly improved. How it's taking around 4 mins

Comment: Wow! What an improvement! It could also just be that if the project is very large, webpack just takes time to build. In that case, it could be beneficial to `eject` and see if there's any [performance optimizations](https://webpack.js.org/guides/build-performance/) that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above mentioned answer I would like to add that shifting from CRA (Create React App) to [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/why.html) would significantly reduce your build time as well as your bundle size.

Create React App (CRA) was once the go-to tool for creating new React projects. It provided a simple and easy-to-use command-line interface (CLI) for setting up new React codebases, complete with a development server, automatic transpilation, and more.

Many devs currently consider CRA to be dead, and is now mostly used by people who are getting started with react.

Vite ships with a pre-configured build command that bakes in many performance optimizations out of the box. So check it out!

Here's an article on why CRA is dead and the best available alternatives:
[Create React App is Dead?](https://dev.to/thevinitgupta/create-react-app-is-dead-3igo)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can achieve a faster build time is by using reusable components in ReactJS.

[resuable components overview](https://medium.com/@livajorge7/creating-reusable-react-components-for-faster-and-more-efficient-development-563b50a537df)

While previously working on a WebRTC application in nodeJS and react, implementing this on the frontend side drastically reduced the build time than before, which usually took 5 minutes earlier.

This is because the `index.html` file tries to combine everything in React to a single file during the build which while not initially an issue affecting the application quickly turns to a bigger problem at higher stage.

Here's a short guide regarding the same:

[resuable components guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-reusable-react-components)

Since there is no code mentioned in the original question, this is all I can think of at this point.